# How to detect the event change of a button being continuously pressed on Android

Tags: android

I need to change the color of the button if it has been pressed for more than two seconds.

Comment: Give specific information about your project such as which API level are you using, your development environment etc. Also what did you try for your work? You have wrench and you are trying to create space shuttle.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use  onTouch() method it allows to check for actions such as ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN
Assign it like that to a button in onCreate()

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

And then in onTouch()

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    switch ( arg1.getAction() ) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        //Start measuring time and when action = up calculate difference in time
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: how can it calculate difference of time?

Comment: Well check current time and then check it again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how long a long click is, but if you don't need it to be exactly two seconds I would register a onLongClickListener for that button.  Then have the listener update the color.

Comment: button2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
       timeDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
     }
     if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
       timeUp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(timeUp - timeDown>2000)  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "> 2 secs",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
return true;
}
});